# How can I configure a static network of TomEE embedded ActiveMQ brokers so that clients can communicate?

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-tomee

I have three TomEE instances running. I'd like to use one as a 'master' broker, and have two other instances connect to the master as clients. I would like for the clients to be able to send / receive messages to one another.

The biggest requirement is that I must use static networking; simply pointing the `ServerUrl` in the clients' `tomee.xml` to the master URL is not an option.

I've verified that I'm able to statically connect two containers and pass messages, but when I introduce the third container (the master), messages stop flowing from 'Client-A' to 'Client-B'

**Master tomee.xml**:

```
<Resource
    id="ra/activemq"
    type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
    BrokerXmlConfig = broker:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616,network:static:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61615,tcp://127.0.0.1:61617))/tomeeActiveMq?useJmx=true
    ServerUrl = tcp://127.0.0.1:61616
</Resource>
```

**Client-A tomee.xml**:

```
<Resource
    id="ra/activemq"
    type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
    BrokerXmlConfig = broker:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61615,network:static:tcp://127.0.0.1:61616)/server0?useJmx=true&amp;persistent=false
    ServerUrl = tcp://127.0.0.1:61615
</Resource>
```

**Client-B tomee.xml**:

```
<Resource
    id="ra/activemq"
    type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
    BrokerXmlConfig = broker:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61617,network:static:tcp://127.0.0.1:61616)/server1?persistent=false&amp;useJmx=true
    ServerUrl = tcp://127.0.0.1:61617
</Resource>
```

My ActiveMQ console shows that both clients are indeed connected to the master via a static network:

[image]

Here is a diagram of broker layout according to HawtIO:

[image: Diagram of broker layout from HawtIO]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3+ broker networks, you need to set the `networkTTL` option to something more than 1, which is default. The TTL option sets the max limit on how many network brokers a message can reach.

So, by default you can communicate c1<->master and c2<->master but not c1<->c2 in the same network.

Not sure how to pass that option via URI in a resource adapter though.

[More about the network of brokers configuration](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html)

Comment: Does the `networkTTL` attribute need to be set on all three, or just on the master? I've configured an `activemq.xml` for the master, and included `uri="static:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61615,tcp://127.0.0.1:61617)" networkTTL="4"` on the `networkConnector` node. Still no c1<->c2 communication.

Comment: I was actually able to achieve this using a combination of the `networkTTL` and setting `duplex="true"` on the master's `activemq.xml`'s `networkConnector` node. I also had to remove the static network in my clients' `tomee.xml` resource configuration, otherwise there were strange errors about names being in use (from the duplex attribute). Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Nice. The duplex option is great since you can control the network connections from a single broker.